# Route method from react-router-dom is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to find a solution for this.
Navbar, Home, Services, Contactus are different components that render fine when I don't user the Route method. They also render fine within the BrowserRouter tags. But when I try to place them within the Route tags, the whole screen goes blank

```
import Contactus from './Contactus';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Home from './Home';
import Services from './Services';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is React Router</h1>
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
        <Route path="/home" Component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/services" Component={Services} exact />
        <Route path="/contactus" Component={Contactus} exact />
      </Router>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In RRDv5 the `Route` component's prop is `component`, not `Component`. See https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component. Voting to close "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: I have replaced Component with component. Still getting the same problem

Comment: Try killing any running code watchers/hot-reloaders and restarting the development server to ensure it's picked up your change. What *exactly* isn't working then? Are there any error messages? Are you using the latest version of `react-router-dom` (v6)? The code snippet you've shared is RRDv5 code/syntax.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese and thanks for your help. Yes, the code snippet was v5 and the installed version was v6. That was the issue

Comment: You need to wrap those Route with Routes(v6) and move Nav outside of them

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this. The library installed was react-router-dom v6 but the coding was done for earlier versions. Below are the changes I made and its now working.

Fixes -

1. All the `<Route>` lines need to be enclosed within a `<Routes>` block
2. For some reason, component is not being accepted as a parameter in the new version so essentially `component={Home}` is now replaced by `element={<Home/>}`
3. And of course, we now need to import Routes also from react-router-dom

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Contactus from './Contactus';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Home from './Home';
import Services from './Services';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is React Router</h1>
      
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} exact />
          <Route path="/services" element={<Services/>}  />
          <Route path="/contactus" element={<Contactus/>}  />
        </Routes>  
      </Router>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that `render` was not working properly on the `Route` tag.

```
{/* Learning react router */}
<Routes>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage} />
  <Route exact path='/about' component={() => <About />} />
  <Route exact path='/contact' component={() => <Contact />} />
  <Route exact path='/service' render={() => <Service name="MyService" />} />
  <Route path="*" component={Error} />
</Routes>
```

As @RamzySyed answered, my issue is solved because of the version I am using `react-router-dom@v6.12.1` which has some changes.

```
<Route exact path='/service' element={<Service name="MyService" />} />
```

If anyone needs full docs: [Upgrade to React Router v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6).

This was informative content for me and don't forget to read [Advantages of Route element](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Route` with `Switch` if you are using v5

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is React Router</h1>
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
       <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" Component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/services" Component={Services} exact />
        <Route path="/contactus" Component={Contactus} exact />
       </Switch>
      </Router>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

or with `Routes` if v6

```
function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>This is React Router</h1>
          <Router>
            <Navbar/>
           <Routes>
            <Route path="/home" Component={Home} exact />
            <Route path="/services" Component={Services} exact />
            <Route path="/contactus" Component={Contactus} exact />
           </Routes>
          </Router>
          
          
        </div>
      );
    }
```